# typescript generic as object key name

Tags: typescript

I'm calling the server with a dynamic field, and the server will respond with an object with that field as the key on object. I've tried all these but they give all bunch of errors

```
function callServer<T>(field, value): IResponse<T> {
  return api.put(url, { [field]: value  })
}

interface IResponse<T> {
  [T]: any
}
interface IResponse<T> {
  [key: T]: any
}
interface IResponse<T extends string> {
  [T]: any
}
```

Is this even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible! If you make sure the field type argument extends `string | number | symbol` and then use a `Record` to make the object structure, it works wonderfully.

```js
function callServer<Field extends string>(field: Field, value: any): Record<Field, any> {
  return api.put(url, { [field]: value })
}

// Type is an object with the key of `'fieldName'` with the value of `any`
const test = callServer('fieldName', { value: 'my test value' })
```

Comment: that works of `fieldName` is a hard coded string, but if I try to pass it as a variable I get "'field' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof field'?"

Comment: Can you create a TypeScript playground with that issue? I am getting a loose type (using `string` instead of the constant value), but I do not get that error.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-bash-423vn?file=/src/index.ts - in the sandbox there's a different error, `field is undefined`

Comment: Yes, `field` (lowercase) is a value, and cannot be passed as a type parameter without using `typeof field`. Also, a neat thing about TypeScript is that it will infer that parameter based on what your function inputs are, so explicitly stating the type parameter is not required.